# How to get position from Adapter and send it to Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, adapter, android-recyclerview

Im trying to get the position of the clicked item from the adapter and send it to an activity but can't seem to make it work.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeViewHolder holder, int position) {
...
...
}
```

I tried to get the position from onBindViewHolder and then send it to the activity and call it in an array:

```
private int[] images = {R.raw.glasses1, R.raw.glasses3, R.raw.glasses4, R.raw.glasses5,
        R.raw.glasses6, R.raw.glasses7, R.raw.glasses8, R.raw.glasses9, R.raw.glasses10};
```

then call

```
images[position]
```

Comment: Inside on click method get the position by getAdapterPosition().Create a listener will send data back to the activity for that position.

Answer (score 1):

try `getAdapterPostion()` method in your adapter and implement listener to pass to activity

Answer (score 1):

While handling the events on the item such as click you should always use the `getAdapterPosition()` method of the holder object instead of the `position` in `onBindViewHolder()` as it is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

Clicked item position in `Adapter` is saved in `getAdapterPosition()` and `getPosition()` method. There is a difference between both, you can check that [here](https://medium.com/@noureldeen.abouelkassem/difference-between-position-getadapterposition-and-getlayoutposition-in-recyclerview-80279a2711d1). I suggest you to use `getAdapterPosition()` Whenever you desired for getting the `Position` of the clicked item.

Answer (score 1):

It worked using getAdapterPosition() method.Inside onBindViewHolder() i've created the onListener() method like following:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    ...
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int pos=holder.getAdapterPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ArActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pos",pos);

        }
    });
}
```

and then got the data in the activity like following inside the the onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
         pos=extras.getInt("pos");

    }
```

where 'pos' is declared inside the activity class.